# Question About Assumption Relating to Bolzano-Weierstrass

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

We had the first day of our topology course today, and the instructor presented the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem on $\mathbb{R}$. I took it as a challenge to see if I could do it while he was talking, so I came up with this:

**Thm**: Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be infinite, where $\mathrm{diam}(A) \leq C < + \infty$, and A is infinte. Then A has at least one limit point.

**Prf**: Let $(x_{k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a strictly increasing sequence of elements of $A$. Then let $\varepsilon_{j} = |x_{j + 1} - x_{j}|$. Then

\begin{align*}
|x_{k + 1} - x_{1}| & = \sum_{j = 1}^{k} \varepsilon_{j} \\
 & < C \\
\Rightarrow \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} \varepsilon_{j} & = L \\
 & \leq C \\
\Rightarrow |L - \sum_{j = 1}^{k} \varepsilon_{j} | & = \sum_{j = k + 1}^{\infty} \varepsilon_{j} \\
 & > \sum_{j = k + 1}^{k + N} \varepsilon_{j} \\
 & = |x_{k + N + 1} - x_{k + 1}| \\
 & \to 0 \textrm{ as $k \to \infty$}
\end{align*}

Thus for each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $k > K$, then for all $N \geq 1$, we have

\begin{align*}
\epsilon & > |L - \sum_{j= 1}^{k} \varepsilon_{j}| \\
 & = \sum_{j = k + 1}^{\infty} \varepsilon_{j} \\
 & > \sum_{j = k + 1}^{k + N} \varepsilon_{j} \\
 & = |x_{k + N + 1} - x_{k + 1}|
\end{align*}

Thus if $k > K$, then $|x_{k + 1} - x_{k + N + 1}| < \epsilon$ for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus $(x_{k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy, and thus by construction of $\mathbb{R}$ the sequence converges, and so $\lim_{k \to \infty} x_{k} \in \mathbb{R}$ is a limit point of $A$. QED.

**My questions**:

Firstly, is the assumption that an infinite subset of $\mathbb{R}$ contains a strictly increasing or strictly decreasing sequence unfounded? Does it accidentally require some weak form of Choice?

Thanks.

Comment: The range of a strictly decreasing sequence of reals is a counter example to your first claim. On the other hand, a nice combinatorial argument (Ramsey-theoretic) gives us that any infinite set of reals contains an increasing sequence or a decreasing one. But yes, this uses a modicum amount of choice.

Comment: I fear I have a rather severe lack of Ramsey theory. Could you give any rough pointers on how that would work?

Comment: You use the ordering of $\mathsf R$, not it's *well-ordering* (a technical term with a different meaning). For $\mathsf R^n $, argue coordinate-wise. The result is false in arbitrary complete spaces.

Comment: Choice is not needed to get a monotone subsequence (note that you don't want to require strictly increasing/decreasing though). The [wikipedia article on Bolzano-Weierstrass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano–Weierstrass_theorem) has the standard proof of this fact, and it's constructive. Edit: Sorry, this is for sequences, not infinite subsets. I think you'll need [countable choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_countable_choice) for this method of proof.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the 'increasing sequence construction' by partitioning your set into pieces.

Take an interval $[a,b]$ containing all the points of $A$ and split it at its midpoint. If the upper half has infinitely many points of $A$, set $a=(a+b)/2)$, otherwise the lower half has infinitely many points of $A$ and set $b=(a+b)/2$. Continue recursively, splitting the interval in half at each time; at least one of the halves will always contain infinitely many points of $A$. The sequence of midpoints of the intervals is Cauchy and so has a limit point $x$. For every $\epsilon>0$ you can find one of your intervals that contains $x$ and is shorter than $\epsilon$ and so contains a point of $A$ (in fact, infinitely many).

You should be able to see how to do this bisection (well, partitioning) in $\mathbb{R}^n$, too.

Comment: The instructor did that same proof, but I was curious as to if my own was sound. It was more for the sake of personal recreation.